Mac and old Adobe Flash Player: HSTS behaviour
I begin by saying that I have recently 'obsessed' with my past browsing history with my old Mac (2017). I also understand that flash is not updated and many won’t have a system on which to test this today.
Example: website URL is visited on January 1st, the settings.sol file Macromedia-support-flash player-sys-url should be updated for that URL and an entry created showing HSTS starting date January 1st and HSTS max age 180 days (in seconds).  I’m interested in what happens to the file after June 30th when the HSTS policy expires and no other visits to that page happen between the entry and expiration passes.
I have a settings.sol file having, let's say, those HSTS info (January 1st and 180 days) which appears to have been created and modified on June 6th even though the browsing history says that that website was visited only on January 1st and not on June 6th.
Is it possible that Flash Player used to automatically update the settings.sol files having an expired HSTS policy to clean them?

Flash is very dead now. It's not going to do anything.

Sorry, you're right. The question in fact Is "do you know what used to happen to a settings.sol file etc... etc ... back in 2017 when Flash used to be alive?" :)
